# express PUT empty body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on making an update request in my REST api built in MEAN Stack.
While submitting a HTTP PUT requrst, i am getting 'req.body' always empty.

I have explored already and i am using following in my REST API server side :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

From the Client Side , This is my request looks like:

```
$http.put('http://localhost:8080/api/applications/'+data.name,
        {params:{'test' : 'testvalue'}},config)
        .success(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
        })
```

When I am trying to get value of test by using 'req.body.test' , i am always getting 'undefined' and on further 'req.body' is empty.

Also ,the client is angular's $http ( angular 1.5.8) and on the Server side i am using the following in the middleware :

```
// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Something is happening.');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});
```

and here is the endpoint in REST API :

```
router.route('/applications/:name')
.put(function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.params.name + "  " + req.body.test);
    res.json({ message: req.body.test});
                 // });
    })
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please include the server function handling that endpoint. Also, is that Angular's $http client or something else? Please specify.

Comment: Yes, the client is angular's $http, and here is the server function handling that endpoint :   router.route('/applications/:name').put(function(req, res) {console.log(req.body.test)});

Comment: Also, i am using the following in the middleware :// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Something is happening.');
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information. This is important, so that people do not have to read the comments in order to understand the question.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I have updated the question

Comment: You may wish to isolate the problem. Observe with the browser's debugging tools whether the request was properly made. Also, the docs on [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) show that you might want the second parameter to be `{test:'testvalue'}` (not inside a `params` field).

Comment: Thank you..looks like changing the parameter and clearing the cookies did the work